# Problem binding XML to a Flex Tree

Tags: apache-flex

I have XML with a value like the following:

```
<products>
  <product id="1" name="All Products">
    <code>000</code>
    <shortname>ALL</shortname>
    <cost>0.0</cost>
    <product id="2" name="Product Group A">
      <code>001</code>
      <shortname>A</shortname>
      <cost>0.0</cost>
      <product id="4" name="Product A">
        <code>11</code>
        <shortname>ProductA</shortname>
        <cost>0.4</cost>
      </product>
    </product>
  </product>
</products>
```

I declare an XMLList by calling xml.children(), and bind it to a tree like so:

```
var products:XMLList = xml.children()

<mx:Tree id="treeProducts" dataProvider="{products}" labelField="@name" width="100%" />
```

However, my tree doesn't know which XML elements to create nodes for, so I get nodes for every element, ie:

> ```
> -All Products
>   - 000
>   - ALL
>   - 0.0
>   - Product Group A
>     - 001
>     - A
>     - 0
> ```

What I really want is just to show the `@name` value for each `<product>`:

> - All Products
>
>   - Product Group A
>
>     - Product A

Am I missing something totally obvious?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, shouldn't code, shortname etc be attributes as well?

Comment: I'm rendering with Grails, which has this type of format by default. But you're right, I could customize the format to make it readily bindable to the tree. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were just collecting nodes from the tree, I would think E4X notation would be the best way to go:

```
xml..(@name != '')
```

(or some such, not checked for accuracy)

That wouldn't preserve the tree structure, though.  Since you want a particular view of the tree data, I'd suggest applying an implementation of [ITreeDataDescriptor](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/treeClasses/ITreeDataDescriptor.html) which filters for named nodes in its methods:

Comment: Yep, that worked. I created a new ITreeDataDescriptor and customized the getChildren method- not too bad. I might wind up just simplifying the XML to just return the <product> hierarchy with only the name attribute, and use it to build the tree. Then, get the other details when needed...